# $wpdb query adding extra value during update query

Tags: wordpress

I am very baffled by this problem.

The below is the very simple function to update a column by adding some more value:

```
public function add_user_to_new_post_sub($email, $sub_post_type) {
     global $wpdb;
     $add_setting = "|||".$sub_post_type;

     //echo $add_setting; exit;

     $wpdb->query(
        "UPDATE $this->subscriptions_table 
        SET subscription_settings = concat(subscription_settings, '$add_setting')
        WHERE user_key = '$key'"
    );
}
```

For some reason, the $sub_post_type is always added 2 times. As an example, if the subscription_settings column has apple in it, and $sub_post_type = orange, the end result after the query would be apple|||orange|||orange. I don't understand why the extra value being added. I even did a sanity check with echo to make sure I am not passing things twice, and I am not.

Please help, I have been struggling for some time now.

Answer (score 1):

I found my reason; the function was being called again through another if statement. doh